# Designing databse for questions and answers where some answers are text and some are multiple choice

Tags: database-design

I know there are a few related posts but I didn't fully understand what to do.

I have a general idea of how to go about this.  I am not too far into database design unfortunately so I require help.

Have table with questions_id, have table for possible_answer_id for each question_id.

Then have a linking table question_answers with user_id, question_id, answer_id, timestamp to register submitted forms.

But my problem is that some questions are answered with just a string so I am having trouble conceptualizing what to do about it.

```
e,g 
for some I need: question_id string_answer (any answer is allowed)
for others:      question_id answer_id     (out of set of allowed answers)
and perhaps:     question_id bool_answer   (true/false)
```

Do I add question_type somewhere so I have two different tables for this?

If the question is not clear, please let me know.

Comment: That's actually a somewhat tricky design issue. Not a N00B question at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edited to take into account Eugene's questions.

Here are the tables that your system will need, and an explanation of each table.

**1. Person**

This table will contain all of the information about the person taking a test.  The key to the table is a person id, which is an integer that automatically increments for each person row added to the table.  Most current databases have an identity integer or auto-incrementing integer, which is normally the primary key of the table.

**2. Question**

This table contains all of the questions that you've ever thought of asking.

The question table would contain a flag (integer or character) that would indicate the type of question, as you've outlined.

- Any string answer
- Set of allotted answers
- True / false

**3. Answer**

This table contains the sets of answers for the questions in the Question table that require a set of allotted answers.  The group key to the set of answers is the primary key of the question.

Programatically, you would select a row from the question table.  Only if the flag is set of allotted answers would you then browse the answer table in a separate SQL query.

**4. Test**

This table contains the date and time the test was created.

**5. Test Question**

This table contains the questions selected from the Question table for one particular test.  The group key for the set of test questions is the Test table id.

The reason for having a Test Question table is questions and answers can be added, changed, or removed from the Question and Answer table.  The Test Questions table is a historical table in that once the rows are added, they are never changed or removed.

**6. Test Taken**

This table contains the Person id of the person that took the test, the Test id of the Test, and the date and time the test was taken.

**7. Test Answer**

This table contains the answers to the test.  The group key to the set of Test Answers is the Test Taken id and the Test Question id.

Comment: Just to be clear, i would have three separate user_question_answer_timestamp tables for each type?  How would I then go to the correct table based on type?

Comment: Is there a way to have a table that would link question_type to a correct_table?  Are there such things as table ids?  I am a little confused : ) Sorry for the trouble, I would appreciate your help.

Comment: @Eugene: You only need a table if you're storing something there.  The only answer that needs additional data is the set of allotted answers.  You're going to have to have more tables to store the tests given and the test answers supplied by the users.  Yes, you could have a table that links the set of allotted answers flag to a table name if you want.

Comment: Thanks for the long reply!  My db is not really relating to testing as to polling but I can abstract what I need from the answer.  But the main issue I have is with (using the test analogy) would be a table that would have Student Answers to Questions on a specific test.  Since answers will be either bool or string or answer_id I cant just have a table that would have student_id time_stamp answer_id.  And that is where my main issue lies.  I,e as it pertains to my case, its not about storing forms with questions as an issue as much as it is about storing users responses to these forms.

Comment: @Eugene: Wouldn't that table be Test Answer (or Poll Answer)?  The Test Answer table has a reference back to the Test Taken.  The Test Taken table has a reference back to the Person.  You don't have to put the person_id in every test answer.

Comment: yeah thats true.  Say form contains 3 questions 1: describe this painting.  2: choose your favorite color(black, red, white). 3: are you a programmer? true/false.  There is no right or wrong answer.  So I need to store it on some table that relates the question id, user-id, form-id, and response which might be a string or might be id to a specific a possible answer to a question.  So i can't see how I can store it on one table since there are multiple potential datatypes involved ( for the answer ).

Comment: I keep using word answer, but I mean to say response to a q or a poll.

Comment: @Eugene: I think I see where the confusion lies.  In the Test Answer table, the answer is stored in a column as a String.  Either it's the string that the poll taker typed, the string from the set of allotted answers that was chosen, "true", or "false".  I suppose if you want, you could have a boolean column for the true / false answer, and set the String to null.  The Test Question id is a foreign key on the Test Answer table.  The Person id is a foreign key on the Test Taken table.  Yes, you would have to join the Test Answer table and the Test Taken table to get the Person information.

Comment: right now I am thinking of having a table with all responses (some of which will be predefined for specific questions and others just constantly inserted with submitted strings from a form).  Then on a table link the id from response table to the question and to the user (or a whole submited_form_id that would include user information).  I hope that makes sense.  Thanks for your help.  I will update my question based on everything.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean.  But the problem with that is I can't afford to loose statistical data which will be very important.  So if I record answers as string and later change a set of answers from say {"like", "don't like"} to {"prefer, don't prefer"} it will be very hard to update the databse to also update the responses and not loose data.  Even though I may change what the answers look like, I want the statistics to stay the same.  I may also want statistics based on questions, not entire forms so as I understand it may be actually better to not attach users to forms as much as responses.

Comment: @Eugene: In that case, you'll have to have a foreign key in the Test Answer table that points back  to the Answer table.  That means you'll have a string for the free form answers, a pointer for the allotted answer, and a boolean for the true / false answer.  Two of the three columns will be null for a given answer, but that's ok.

Answer (score 2):

Try these three tables.

```
QUESTION_MASTER

QuestionID    int  (Primary)
QuestionName  varchar(150)
QuestionType  tinyint
CorrectAns1   bit          -- for true/false
CorrectAns2   varchar(500) -- for string answer
CorrectAns3   int          -- for multiple choice

ANSWER_MASTER

AnswerID      int  (Primary)
QuestionID    int  (Foreign)
CorrectAns    bit

EXAM_MASTER

ExamID        int(Primary)
QuestionID    int(Foreign)
CreatedBy     int(Foreign) --UserID
```

Use this for all three kinds of your question i.e. multiple choice, fill the blank and true/false questions.